# while(true) and Collections

Tags: java, collections, while-loop

I can't understand the difference between these two codes;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
      list.add("Hello");
    }
  }
```

which throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` ***within a second***,

**AND**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
      list.add("Hello");
      System.out.println(list.size());  // Simply display the size of List
    }
  }
```

which throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` ***after 5 minutes*** with the list.size() having the value 20767725.

Comment: The print function is so slow that it takes "about 5 minutes" to die.
(list add is not much more than 'pointer-chaining')

Comment: your printing to the console every 'add' this will take it a while longer. Any interaction with the GUI is going to slow it down. I would guess if you put the println in an if statement to say only print every X times then it will speed up proportionally

Comment: Remove the println from both and run again to see which one is faster.

Comment: @Stolas: Actually with `ArrayList`, there can be a significant copy operation. It's not a linked list as you comment sort of implies·

Comment: I'm sorry guys. I run this code again and it took about 3 minutes. Maybe because some running applications were slowing it down or I did some mistake in timing it. @JonSkeet is right.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for correcting me, I made an assumption :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply put - it takes quite a while to display 20 million lines of text.

It's easy enough to show that. Run this code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20767725; x++) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

I suspect that'll take about 5 minutes as well.

Comment: @Tarik The difference is obviously because Collections is not involved in this loop.

Comment: @Mawia: No, that's not obvious at all. It really shouldn't make a significant difference, given that on its own it fails in a second. How are you timing this?

Answer (score 3):

It is behaving as expected. In the first code, the system doesn't have to wait for communications to monitor ( i.e. external device). The only communication is between RAM and the processor, which happens at billions of calculations per second. So the memory runs out quickly.

In the Second Code: after every addtolist, the item has to be displayed on console. the output operations to interfaces are much much slower than CPU to RAM interactions. So the process is put to halt until "Hello" is displayed, and it continues again, thus taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println()` is an IO operation which takes some time.  That explains the difference between 'a second' and '5 minutes'.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println()` requires much times to executes as its relate to IO Operation.

Comment: No, the *compiler* doesn't need much time at all. The difference is at *execution* time, not compile-time.

Comment: Ya, i need to reform my answer. Compiler doesn't takes time,all time is wasted on execution. Thanks for your comment Jon Skeet.